# How to combine NHibernate Fluent and the VmWrapper-Classes from the WPF-NHibernate Toolkit?

Tags: c#, wpf, hibernate, nhibernate, orm

I'm currently experimenting with the [WPF NHibernate toolkit](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WpfNhibernateToolkit.aspx) and I have to say: it's a cool piece of software.

The thing is I am stuck with is. The fact that I use Fluent for NHibernate and with Fluent the view model classes (Mappingfiles) have to be inherited from ClassMap. Where do I have to do this change?

Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

only the mapping classes must inherit from ClassMap<> not the viewmodels which have nothing to do with persistence. If you want to persist viewmodels you have to write viewmodelmap classes.

Comment: good idea! What i did, was to inherit VmObjectBase<DM> from ClassMap<DM> and implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged. Do you think this is against the principles of MVVM?

Comment: INPC is for UI, ClassMap for persistence, i would rather create ClassMaps seperated from the view models for Seperation of Concerns. you can also automap viewmodels to persist them.